# Prophecies in Durga Saptashati

Tags: durga, markandeya-purana, durga-saptasati

There are various prophecies made Mother Durga in 11 chapter of Durga Saptashati (also known as Devi Mahatmya or Chandi path) present in Markandeya Purana. These prophecies are made by Devi after slaying Shumbh Nishumbh and Devas' prayers. These are [as follows.](https://astro121.com/index.php/durga-saptashati-in-english/durga-saptashati-chapter-11)

> The Devi said:
>
> 40-41. ‘When the twenty-eighth age has arrived during the period of
> Avaisvsvata Manu, two other great asuras, Sumbha and Nisumbha will be
> born.
>
> 42. ‘Then born from the womb of Yasoda, in the home of cowherd Nanda, and dwelling on the Vindhya mountains, I will destroy them both.
> 43. ‘And again having incarnated in a very terrible form on the earth, I shall slay the danavas, who are the descendants of Vipracitti.
> 44. ‘When I shall devour the fierce and great asuras descended from Vipracitti, my teeth shall become red like the flower of pomegranate.
> 45. ‘Therefore when devas in heaven and men on the earth praise me, shall always talk of me as the ‘Red-toothed’(Raktadantika).
> 46. ‘And again when rain shall fail for a period of hundred years, propitiated by the munis I shall be born on the drought-ridden earth,
>     but not womb-begotten.
> 47. ‘Then I shall behold the munis with a hundred eyes and so mankind shall glorify me as the ‘hundred-eyed’(Satakashi).
> 48. ‘At that time, O devas, I shall maintain the whole world with life -sustaining vegetables, born out of my own (cosmic) body, till rains set in.
> 49. ‘I shall be famed on the earth then as Sakambhari. At that very period I shall slay the great asura named Durgama.
>
> 50-53. ‘Thereby I shall have the celebrated name of Durgadevi and
> again, assuming a terrible form on the mountain Himalaya, I shall
> destroy the raksasas for the protection of the munis. Then all the
> munis, bowing their bodies reverently, shall praise me, and thereby I
> shall have the celebrated name of Bhimadevi. When the (asura) named
> Aruna shall work great havoc in the three worlds, having taken a
> (collective) bee-form, consisting of innumerable bees, I shall slay
> the great asura for the good of the world.
>
> 54-55. ‘And then people shall laud me every where as Bhramari. Thus
> whenever trouble arises due to the advent of the danavas, I shall
> incarnate and destroy the foes.’

I assume the incarnation/avatars of Devi as the daughter of Nanda, as Raktadantika, Satakshi, Sakambari, Bhimadevi and Bhramari have already happened. My question is which other avatars of Devi are mentioned in Durga Saptashati?